# Combining Bubble and Sankey Diagram Google Charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, bubble-chart, sankey-diagram

I'm trying to combine Bubble Chart and Sankey Diagram elements from Google Charts, but am having a hard time getting them to display on a page. (This is sample code from Google).  When I isolate the code for just the Bubble Chart or just the Sankey Diagram, they work - but putting them together, nothing happens.  I made sure to set unique variable names, not sure what else I am missing.  Also I literally have no coding experience, just some familiarity with Python, so I may be completely oversimplifying this.  Thanks for the help!

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["sankey"]});

      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['ID', 'Life Expectancy', 'Fertility Rate', 'Region',     'Population'],
          ['CAN',    80.66,              1.67,      'North America',  33739900],
          ['DEU',    79.84,              1.36,      'Europe',         81902307],
          ['DNK',    78.6,               1.84,      'Europe',         5523095],
          ['EGY',    72.73,              2.78,      'Middle East',    79716203],
          ['GBR',    80.05,              2,         'Europe',         61801570],
          ['IRN',    72.49,              1.7,       'Middle East',    73137148],
          ['IRQ',    68.09,              4.77,      'Middle East',    31090763],
          ['ISR',    81.55,              2.96,      'Middle East',    7485600],
          ['RUS',    68.6,               1.54,      'Europe',         141850000],
          ['USA',    78.09,              2.05,      'North America',  307007000]
        ]);

        var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
          data2.addColumn('string', 'From');
          data2.addColumn('string', 'To');
          data2.addColumn('number', 'Weight');
          data2.addRows([
           [ 'A', 'X', 5 ],
           [ 'A', 'Y', 7 ],
           [ 'A', 'Z', 6 ],
           [ 'B', 'X', 2 ],
           [ 'B', 'Y', 9 ],
           [ 'B', 'Z', 4 ],
        ]); 

        var options = {
          title: 'Correlation between life expectancy, fertility rate and population of some world countries (2010)',
          hAxis: {title: 'Life Expectancy'},
          vAxis: {title: 'Fertility Rate'},
          bubble: {textStyle: {fontSize: 11}}
        };

        var options2 = {
          width: 600,
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.BubbleChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);

        var chart2 = new google.visualization.Sankey(document.getElementById('sankey_basic'));
        chart2.draw(data2, options2);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="sankey_basic" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this code the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

is reported for line:

```
var chart2 = new google.visualization.Sankey(document.getElementById('sankey_basic'));
```

The error is same as if the package `sankey` is not loaded.

Changing the line:

```
  google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["sankey"]});
```

to

```
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["sankey"]});
```

loads both diagrams.

Google [sankey docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/sankey#Loading) shows version 1, some examples use version 1.1 which is confusing.